# In this case, will C# use reflection or casting?

Tags: c#, string, dynamic, reflection

In c#, if I write code like this

```
dynamic target = "abcde";
dynamic arg = "c";
Console.WriteLine(target.Contains(arg));
```

Will C# use reflection to get the method "Contains," or cast dynamic as a string automatically and call the method "Contains"?

Comment: How dynamic binding is done is implementation-defined, as said in the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1233-dynamic-binding).

Comment: And "what will the compiler do here" questions are often most easily answered by *compiling the code*. Providing you're not using an obfuscator (and why would you if you're trying to find out what the code is compiled to) the resulting IL is usually easily extracted.